# Tableau Data Dictionary

Tags: tableau-api

I have multiple dashboard with multiple views in it in tableau.
Some of the KPI's are shared among many views.

How to create a metadata/search tool that will help help me identify all the dashboards/views that have a particular search term(KPI) attached with it.
Using the search tool i also want to identify all the TDE attached with it.

Does tableau have this functionality as in-built?

Comment: You can try using `Parameters`

Comment: Do you mean selecting the KPI should filter the reports in dashboard and show only those with KPI and hide where that KPI doesn't exist

Comment: Hey Siva, what I meant was suppose there are currently 20 dashboards with 5 views each. I want to create a search box or filter box  where if i write anything suppose a KPI which is used in 6 different views of 4 different dashboards then it will filter out all those dashboards, views and respected TDE attached with them.

Comment: Interworks has a tool that can provide that level of detail for you. https://www.interworks.com/solutions/business-intelligence/data-visualization/power-tools-tableau. You can also check Tableau Server's Postgres data dictionary. That might have what you're looking for. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/data_dictionary.html